# How to disable shape copy paste with vba in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

i have few flowchart shapes in excel sheet. which i use for label designing purpose. but i don't want to allow user to copy paste selected shape object in same worksheet.

i tried following.

```
Application.copyObjectsWithCells = False

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

But above lines doesn't seems work. how can i disable copy paste for shape still allowing to edit and design textframe character text. 
Help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Is your objective to prevent your artwork/data from being copied/stolen? Or is it that you want to prevent alteration of your template/workbook?

Comment: No, actually if user copy paste shape, its name don't get changed with copy paste &  which create problem with other part of coding. i want copied shape to have unique name or just disable it. thanks for your queries. any workaround ?

Comment: @FaneDuru can you please have a look on thread.

Comment: please have a look https://i.stack.imgur.com/daAFw.png

Comment: It is slightly complicated but can be achievable if **[1.]** You use Custim UI Editor to show/hide the paste button from the ribbon (Effects only the relevant workbook) **[2.]** disable the right click **[3]** Trap keys Ctrl +  V and Shift + Insert

Comment: can we rename pasted shape with unique name automatically after paste  instead of disable copy paste ? @SiddharthRout

Comment: I am not disabling paste. I am just disabling `Home | Paste` and `Right Click`. One can still paste via Ctrl + V and Shift + Insert. The reason why I am doing that is because you cannot (I could be wrong) trap those events. You can disable pasting of shapes or rename shapes when you trap the keys as mentioned in point 3 above